# How can I access the instantiated user within the user model itself (without creating another relationship)?

Tags: laravel

I want to create a custom method by accessing the instantiated users id, like:

```
public function ware(){
    return File::where('owner', $this->user->id);
}
```

same could be a accessor or scope. and then being able to call

```
$user = User::find(5);
$user->ware()->all()...
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$this->id` or even `$this->attributes['id']` instead of `$this->user->id` since `ware()` is an instance method of `User`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would define relationships using PK/FK as outlined in the Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) and then could access them via relationship like:

*Make sure your file table has a column for `user_id` which would allow the relationship to function as outlined above.*

**Add to User Model**:

```
/**
 * Get the files for the user.
 */
public function files()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\File');
}
```

**Add to File Model**:

```
/**
 * Get the user for the file.
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}
```

You could then access it like `User::find(5)->files` (*to get user files*) or `File::find(5)->user` to return the file user.